# How to increase tilesize for OSM database

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm trying to create a custom tileserver with express and Postgres. I've imported the OSM planet.pbf file into a Postgres database with PostGIS installed and I can currently serve tiles in 256x256, however I want to increase the tilesize to 512x512 or even 1024x1024.

I've tried to increase the tilesize by changing the extent from `0` to `512` and setting the ST_TileEnvelope's margin to both `64.0/4096` and `0.125` (which I gathered from [the docs](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_TileEnvelope.html) is equal to a tilesize of 512).

Here's the query I use for retrieving the tile

```sql
SELECT ST_AsMvt(q, 'geom') FROM (
    SELECT
       ST_AsText(ST_AsMVTGeom(
            ST_Multi(ST_Collect(way)),
            TileBBox($1, $2, $3, 3857),
            4096,
            0,
            false
        )) as st_asmvt
    FROM planet_osm_polygon
    WHERE ST_Intersects(way, ST_TileEnvelope($1, $2, $3))
    GROUP BY osm_id
) q;
```

Answer (score 2):

I have created a fix for my issue. I replaced the TileBBox function with the one below, allowing a 5th parameter to be passed with the tilesize.

```sql
create or replace function TileBBox(z int, x int, y int, srid int = 3857, tileSize int = 256)
    returns geometry
    language plpgsql immutable as
$func$
declare
    defaultTilesize numeric := 256;
    max numeric := 20037508.34;
    res numeric := (max*2)/(2^z);
    bbox geometry;
    multiplier numeric;
begin
    multiplier := tileSize / defaultTilesize;
    bbox := ST_MakeEnvelope(
                -max + (x * res * multiplier),
                max - (y * res * multiplier),
                -max + (x * res  * multiplier) + res * multiplier,
                max - (y * res  * multiplier) - res * multiplier,
                3857
        );

    if srid = 3857 then
        return bbox;
    else
        return ST_Transform(bbox, srid);
    end if;
end;
$func$;
```

The query to select the tiles has been replaced with this one (the only change was the ST_TileEnvelope in the where clause):

```sql
SELECT ST_AsMvt(q, 'geom') FROM (
    SELECT
       ST_AsText(ST_AsMVTGeom(
            ST_Multi(ST_Collect(way)),
            TileBBox($1, $2, $3, 3857, 512),
            4096,
            0,
            false
        )) as st_asmvt
    FROM planet_osm_polygon
    WHERE ST_Intersects(way, ST_TileBBox($1, $2, $3, 4857, 512))
    GROUP BY osm_id
) q;
```